# Should I use "sample_weights" on a calibrator if I already used them while training the model (imbalanced dataset)?

Tags: probability-calibration, imbalanced-data

I was wondering what is the right way to proceed when you are dealing with an imbalanced dataset and you want to use a calibrator. When I work with a single model and imbalanced datasets I usually pass "sample_weights" to the model, but I don't know if "sample_weights" should be passed to the calibrator as well.